# How to make work the i686 version of ubuntu 18.04 (emulated with exagear) on the jetson nano

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, arm, emulation

I’ve installed exagear on my jetson nano and I have also activated an old license that I’d bought some time ago. Actually I’m trying to understand what to do further. I have installed the i686 version of ubuntu 18.04 as guest os,but it does not work properly. what’s missing ? below u can see what happens after having invoked the “exagear” command :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor : 0
vendor_id : Elbrus Technologies
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : Exagear Virtual i686-compatible CPU @ 1.00GHz
stepping : 2526
cpu MHz : 1000.00
cache size : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu pse tsc cx8 apic pge cmov clflush mmx pxsr sse sse2 nx pni ssse3 sse4_1 lahf_lm
bogomips : 1000.00
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor : 1
vendor_id : Elbrus Technologies
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : Exagear Virtual i686-compatible CPU @ 1.00GHz
stepping : 2526
cpu MHz : 1000.00
cache size : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 1
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 1
initial apicid : 1
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu pse tsc cx8 apic pge cmov clflush mmx pxsr sse sse2 nx pni ssse3 sse4_1 lahf_lm
bogomips : 1000.00
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor : 2
vendor_id : Elbrus Technologies
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : Exagear Virtual i686-compatible CPU @ 1.00GHz
stepping : 2526
cpu MHz : 1000.00
cache size : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 2
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 2
initial apicid : 2
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu pse tsc cx8 apic pge cmov clflush mmx pxsr sse sse2 nx pni ssse3 sse4_1 lahf_lm
bogomips : 1000.00
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor : 3
vendor_id : Elbrus Technologies
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : Exagear Virtual i686-compatible CPU @ 1.00GHz
stepping : 2526
cpu MHz : 1000.00
cache size : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 3
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 3
initial apicid : 3
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu pse tsc cx8 apic pge cmov clflush mmx pxsr sse sse2 nx pni ssse3 sse4_1 lahf_lm
bogomips : 1000.00
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# bash

root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# apt-get install
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree… Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# apt-get install wine
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree… Done
E: Unable to locate package wine

root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# arch
i686

root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario/Desktop# sudo apt-get update
sudo: getrlimit: Function not implemented
sudo: setrlimit: Function not implemented
sudo: setrlimit: Function not implemented
sudo: getrlimit: Function not implemented
sudo: setrlimit: Function not implemented
sudo: setrlimit: Function not implemented
Err:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
System error resolving ‘archive.canonical.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eltechs/jpeg8/ubuntu xenial InRelease
System error resolving ‘ppa.launchpad.net:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eltechs/wine3.0-dsound/ubuntu bionic InRelease
System error resolving ‘ppa.launchpad.net:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
System error resolving ‘security.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Err:7 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
Reading package lists… Done
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease System error resolving ‘security.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease System error resolving ‘it.archive.ubuntu.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease System error resolving ‘archive.canonical.com:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eltechs/jpeg8/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease System error resolving ‘ppa.launchpad.net:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eltechs/wine3.0-dsound/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease System error resolving ‘ppa.launchpad.net:http’ - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this may help :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:~# sudo --version

Sudo version 1.8.21p2
Configure options: --build=i686-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir={prefix}/include --mandir={prefix}/share/man --infodir={prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir={prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-exampledir=/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p: --without-lecture --with-tty-tickets --disable-root-mailer --enable-admin-flag --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/run/sudo --libexecdir=/usr/lib/sudo --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --with-selinux --with-linux-audit --enable-tmpfiles.d=yes
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers file grammar version 46

Sudoers path: /etc/sudoers
Authentication methods: ‘pam’
Syslog facility if syslog is being used for logging: authpriv
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates successfully: notice
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates unsuccessfully: alert
Send mail if user authentication fails
Send mail if the user is not in sudoers
Lecture user the first time they run sudo
Require users to authenticate by default
Root may run sudo
Allow some information gathering to give useful error messages
Require fully-qualified hostnames in the sudoers file
Visudo will honor the EDITOR environment variable
Set the LOGNAME and USER environment variables
Length at which to wrap log file lines (0 for no wrap): 80
Authentication timestamp timeout: 15.0 minutes
Password prompt timeout: 0.0 minutes
Number of tries to enter a password: 3
Umask to use or 0777 to use user’s: 022
Path to mail program: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Flags for mail program: -t
Address to send mail to: root
Subject line for mail messages: *** SECURITY information for %h ***
Incorrect password message: Sorry, try again.
Path to lecture status dir: /var/lib/sudo/lectured
Path to authentication timestamp dir: /run/sudo/ts
Default password prompt: [sudo] password for %p:
Default user to run commands as: root
Value to override user’s $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

Path to the editor for use by visudo: /usr/bin/editor
When to require a password for ‘list’ pseudocommand: any
When to require a password for ‘verify’ pseudocommand: all
File descriptors >= 3 will be closed before executing a command
Reset the environment to a default set of variables

Environment variables to check for sanity:
TZ
TERM
LINGUAS
LC_*
LANGUAGE
LANG
COLORTERM

Environment variables to remove:
=()
RUBYOPT
RUBYLIB
PYTHONUSERBASE
PYTHONINSPECT
PYTHONPATH
PYTHONHOME
TMPPREFIX
ZDOTDIR
READNULLCMD
NULLCMD
FPATH
PERL5DB
PERL5OPT
PERL5LIB
PERLLIB
PERLIO_DEBUG
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
SHELLOPTS
BASHOPTS
GLOBIGNORE
PS4
BASH_ENV
ENV
TERMCAP
TERMPATH
TERMINFO_DIRS
TERMINFO
RLD*
LD*
PATH_LOCALE
NLSPATH
HOSTALIASES
RES_OPTIONS
LOCALDOMAIN
CDPATH
IFS

Environment variables to preserve:
XAUTHORIZATION
XAUTHORITY
PS2
PS1
PATH
LS_COLORS
KRB5CCNAME
HOSTNAME
HOME
DPKG_COLORS
DISPLAY
COLORS

Locale to use while parsing sudoers: C
Directory in which to store input/output logs: /var/log/sudo-io
File in which to store the input/output log: %{seq}
Add an entry to the utmp/utmpx file when allocating a pty
PAM service name to use: sudo
PAM service name to use for login shells: sudo
Attempt to establish PAM credentials for the target user
Create a new PAM session for the command to run in
Maximum I/O log sequence number: 0
Enable sudoers netgroup support
Check parent directories for writability when editing files with sudoedit
Allow commands to be run even if sudo cannot write to the audit log
Allow commands to be run even if sudo cannot write to the log file
Log entries larger than this value will be split into multiple syslog messages: 960
File mode to use for the I/O log files: 0600
Execute commands by file descriptor instead of by path: digest_only
Type of authentication timestamp record: tty

Local IP address and netmask pairs:
192.168.1.3/255.255.255.0
172.17.0.1/255.255.0.0
172.30.32.1/255.255.254.0

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.21p2
```

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.21p2

this is what happens when I'm inside the exagear guest os (ubuntu 18.04)

```
root@ziomario-desktop:~# ping www.google.it
ping: www.google.it: System error
root@ziomario-desktop:~# exit
exit
```

this is what happens when I've logged out from the exagear guest os :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario# ping www.google.it
PING www.google.it (216.58.206.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr35s10-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.206.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from lhr35s10-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.206.35): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=18.5 ms
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "doesn't work properly"? If the problem is with `apt update` then it is because you are not properly connected to the internet.

Comment: I'm not able to connect the guest os to internet,but when I exit exagear,you see that I'm connected : check this : Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.21p2
root@ziomario-desktop:~# ping www.google.it
ping: www.google.it: System error
root@ziomario-desktop:~# exit
exit
root@ziomario-desktop:/home/ziomario# ping www.google.it
PING www.google.it (216.58.206.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr35s10-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.206.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from lhr35s10-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.206.35): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=18.5 ms
^C

Comment: I have no idea what exagear is, but you need to have the guest machine to be connected to the internet to be able to get updates. As simple as that. I don't see a question about Ubuntu here.

Comment: Im not able to get internet when I'm inside ubuntu guest os. and it's ubuntu. I see that the question is partially tied to ubuntu.

Comment: If you install any other system this way, you won't have an insternet connection uless you configure something with exagear or whatever. So I am voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: man,exagear closed the activities 1 year ago. I can't ask help to them.

Comment: Why would you expect we can help with it here?

Comment: where I can get help ? ubuntu is involved,exagear is dead. tell me another place where I can ask for some help.